# Find all irreducible monic polynomials of degree 3 in $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z[x].$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This question gives me a good way to count them: [Determine the number of irreducible monic polynomials of degree 3 in $\mathbb F_p[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301852/determine-the-number-of-irreducible-monic-polynomials-of-degree-3-in-mathbb-f)

This question gives me a way to find them that I don't understand, since I haven't yet studied splitting fields: [Irreducible 3rd degree polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588401/irreducible-3rd-degree-polynomials-over-mathbbz-3-field)

My though process so far is:
A reducible polynomial of degree 3 would factor into a quadratic factor and a linear factor. Thus, an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ would have no zeros in $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z.$ Taking into consideration that we need $f(0)\neq 0,$ $f(x)$ must have the form
$$
f(x) = x^3 + bx^2 + cx + d,
$$
where $d=1$ or $-1.$ Then by a quick extension of Fermat's little theorem, $\forall x \in \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z,$ $x^3 = x.$ Thus, we are searching for polynomials without zeros of the form
$$
f(x) = bx^2 + (1+c)x + d.
$$
I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Any advice?

Comment: In your preamble, you've made a common mistake: $\mathbf{F}_{27}$ is a **very** different ring than $\mathbf{Z} / 27 \mathbf{Z}$! For example, $1+1+1 = 0$ in the former, but $1+1+1 \neq 0$ in the latter.

Comment: What is the difference between the two? I would think that $1+1+1\neq 0$ in both.

Comment: @justin, if you know about quotient rings you can think of $F_{27}$ as $F_3[x]/f$ where $f$ is an irreducible cubic, for example $f=x^3+x^2+x-1$.

Comment: I just started to study quotient rings, but this problem comes in my textbook before the quotient rings section. I just realized that interpreting $\mathbb F_{27}$ as $\mathbb Z/27\mathbb Z$ makes no sense because the latter is not a field.

Comment: No, $\mathbb F_{27}$ makes good sense, it is (up to isomorphism) the *only* field with $27$ elements.

Comment: @justin, that is exactly right $\mathbb{Z}/27\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, for example because $3\times 9 = 27 =0$ and you can never have non zero elements that multiply to zero in a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just enumerate all the monic cubic polynomials, there are only $27$ of them, and as you know the constant can’t be zero, so you’re already reduced to writing down $18$ polynomials and testing whether $1$ or $-1$ is a root. I’m computationally inclined, and I would find this a nice $15$ minutes’ exercise. Maybe shorter.

Comment: Alright, thanks! After I learn more about finite fields, I'll check out your answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Mathematica has a function for testing whether a polynomial is irreducible mod 3. Using this, here is the list that I found:
$$ 1+2 x+x^3$$
$$2+2 x+x^3$$
$$2+x^2+x^3$$
$$2+x+x^2+x^3$$
$$1+2 x+x^2+x^3$$
$$1+2 x^2+x^3$$
$$1+x+2 x^2+x^3$$
$$ 2+2 x+2 x^2+x^3$$
If you are interested here is the short code used to produce this:

`list = Flatten[
  Table[x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c, {a, 0, 2}, {b, 0, 2}, {c, 0, 2}]]
For[i = 1, i <= 27, i++, 
 If[IrreduciblePolynomialQ[list[[i]], Modulus -> 3], Print[list[[i]]],
   Print[]]]`